# Maximizing a wpf window when hiding some controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to maximize a wpf window in my program when I click a button , I'have written this code but it doesn't maximize.

```
    private void ShowHideMotorsButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            Motor1WFH.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Motor2WFH.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            MainTabControl.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 165, 12);
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

xaml code:

```
    <Grid >
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,43,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Name="Motor1WFH">
        <apt:MG17Motor x:Name="Motor1" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,249,11,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Name="Motor2WFH">
        <apt:MG17Motor x:Name="Motor2" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    <TabControl Margin="12,12,318,12" Name="MainTabControl">
    ...
```

but the below code works:

```
    private void ShowHideMotorsButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            Motor1WFH.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Motor2WFH.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

when I don't set Margin for MainTabControl.

how I can Maximize it and what goes wrong?

(as you can see in the first picture I have window and when i click on the left button corner to maximize it and hide some controls , it does not completely maximized.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Post a screenshot of what you get versus what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example that may be of use, place the left side controls in their own grid. First the xaml:

```
    <Grid  Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="+"/>
            <TabItem Header="-"/>
            <TabItem Header="Other"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Option 1"/>
            <TabItem Header="Option 2"/>
            <TabItem Header="Option 3"/>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Background="Black" Width="30" Height="20" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="OnExpBtnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then the code behind:

```
    private void OnExpBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_exp)
        {
            _exp = false;
            MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = _origWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            _exp = true;
            _origWidth = MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width;
            MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(0.0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }
     }
```

Where the following are class scope

```
    private bool _exp;
    private GridLength _origWidth;
```

Comment: @abdolah I didn't want to get overly cumbersome, but ideally you should eventually change that `private GridLength _origWidth` to a dependency prop (or at least a property) etc.